# Is there any coding standards for x86 assembler?

Tags: assembly, coding-style, code-standards

I'm looking for something like MISRA or HICPP, but for assembly language. We kind of have an assorted bunch of style and security rules in our company and I suppose every coding community has its own set of useful customs. But is there any industry wide standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found that there are some standards regarding style. Like Randall Hydes from [here](http://www.sourceformat.com/coding-standard-asm.htm). But no common wide standards regarding solely security and robustness like MISRA-C.

Although, there are some industry standards, which address assembly language in this regard. For instance, IEC 60880-2004 has eight rules about using assembler specifically and several more regarding modularity, addressing and interruption usage. I presume, other industry standards, such as DO 178-B or IEC 61508, might have some rules too.